# Cannot connect to AWS Ubuntu instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-18.04

I can't connect to my AWS Ubuntu instance via Putty, before everything was fine, I connected via putty, the security group was configured, port 22 SSH was open for incoming calls.
But when  I started Nginxs I could not  connect via Putty with error "connection timed out",  if I type IP in the browser, I see that nginxs is working,  but IP does not ping ...

Comment: In order for ping to work, you would need to allow ICMP in the Security Group.

Comment: Thank you, but main problem, that I cannot connect anymore via putty

Comment: The best option is to try using `ssh -v` when trying to connect. If you can't find what's wrong, post the output here, but please obfuscate sensitive information.